# Best way in GTest to handle a "warning" situation?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

With GTest, **if a test detects a situation that the test run is not meaningful, what should the test do?**

Thoughts that come to mind:

1. Issue a **warning** through GTest, which would be listed in the end-of-run summary.
   But I've seen nothing in the framework, so don't think this exists.
2. Re-run the test / run in a loop.  But it's using a test fixture and it would have
   to call or duplicate the TearDown/SetUp within the loop. Again I've seen nothing in
   GTest to support this; is there any sort of *Flaky* test support?
3. Issue a warning to stdout and hope the person running the test understands 
   the implications.
4. Just blindly ignore the problem.

The particulars for this instance: I have a function which handles sorting output from parallel threads.  The unit test checks that some outputs from the threads are out of order. Hence, if the check fails, the test is almost meaningless.

Given the random nature of the input generation, I expect a failed check occasionally (<1% of runs) and while it is *not* a FAILURE, if something elsewhere changes and the check fails *all* of the time then the test needs to be fixed.

Comment: I think you need to refactor or remove your test. How would gtest be able to detect a test is meaningful, I feel like it is the authors job to ensure it IS meaningful.

Comment: 6 years to late but you should mock the output of your threads and that way you can control that input is out of order.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like your unit test is bad.

A unit test should be deterministic yet your unit test has random inputs. Say it fails 1% of the time. If you get a failure, how do you expect to debug your unit test if every time you run it the inputs will be different?

You should rewrite your unit test to be deterministic. Random inputs are bad, but pre-determined input sequences, even if they appear random are ok. Try and come up with a good set of input values that can test the corner cases of your algorithm.

If this is not possible, or even it if is, you should ensure that the algorithm is also stress tested in your integration test suite.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my question -- it's about how to indicate to the framework that a test neither passed nor failed. That's why I added the "particulars" at the end

Comment: But beyond that, I seriously disagree with your idea that "A unit test should be deterministic" -- in any moderately complex algorithm, that would artificially and _seriously_ limit coverage, with no benefit.  In this case it's dozens of parallel threads, but even with a PRNG, one would simply print the PRNG seed and (for debugging) have a mechanism whereby the seed could be injected into the test.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand your question. I think you misunderstand what Unit Tests are supposed to be, do, and their limits. Unit Tests aren't supposed to replace all testing for your software. They are only meant to test each individual unit in your software in isolation so that when you integrate the units, you have confidence that each works as specified. I encourage you to read about [FIRST](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) and look around for widely available literature about unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

If your test is not applicable you can abort it without failing it via

```
GTEST_SKIP()
```

This is basically your first suggestion. Skipped tests will be listed separately from failed ones. Typically they do not cause a CI to mark the run as failed.

Skipping tests could be helpful for example if you have a list of generated tests and some specific input combinations are not of interest hence they are skipped. An alternative is to improve the input generator if possible.